# Google API Client - Create user with another email

Tags: php, api, directory, ldap

I started using the php quickstart to connect and create users. Everything works, but cannot add a second email address.

The help is confusing, and can't find an example.

My code so far:

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

// USER DATA
$userName = 'Test';
$userSurname = 'User';
$userDocument = '12345678';
$userEmail = 'test@mail.com';

$name = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();
$email = new Google_Service_Directory_UserEmail();
$user = new Google_Service_Directory_User();

// CREATE USER TO INSERT
$name->setGivenName($userName);
$name->setFamilyName($userSurname);
$name->setFullName($userName . ' ' . $userSurname);

$email->setAddress($userEmail);
$email->setType('home');

$user->setName($name);
$user->setHashFunction('SHA-1');
$user->setPassword(hash('sha1', $userDocument));
$user->setPrimaryEmail($userName . '.' . $userSurname . '@domain.com');
$user->setSuspended(false);
$user->setChangePasswordAtNextLogin(true);
$user->setEmails(array('address' => 'test@mail.com', 'type' => 'home',     'customType' => '', 'primary' => false)); // don't work
// $user->setEmails($email); // don't work either
$user->setOrgUnitPath('/org/path');

try 
{ 
    $createUserResult = $service->users->insert($user); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error. The setEmails method receives an multidimensional array, so:

$user->setEmails(array(array('address' => 'test@mail.com', 'type' => 'home',     'customType' => '', 'primary' => false)));